# Is it ok to insert NOW() into a VARCHAR column?

Tags: mysql

This works fine in MySQL 5.6 but is it ok to do this and is it future-proof?

```
create table test (`test_column` varchar(100));
insert into test values (now());
```

Comment: Is should be. As formatting of now will not be changed in near future.

Comment: I would not suggest you create a column as string but save data is DateTime.Why not just use `datetime` directly?

Comment: It is not common, but it may be ok to do that.  What is your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Although we cannot always predict the future, MySQL has always, and likely always will use the [ISO-8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which is very well specified.

Storing a date value in a string column is a rather odd thing to do, especially if you want it to be a date or date-time. Use the appropriate column type, either `DATE` or `DATETIME` as native representation provides a lot of benefits: Faster indexing, lighter storage requirements, automatic validation, and compatibility with the various date functions MySQL has built-in.

I can't think of a good reason to represent at date as some arbitrary `VARCHAR` column in MySQL.